# Beam pipeline spark runner issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink, apache-beam, data-pipeline

i have a beam pipeline that reads from a kinesis stream, deserialized protobuf data inside, change to byte array and writes it to another kinesis stream (just a dummy pipeline)

This pipeline executes successfully if i run

`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.StarterPipeline -Dexec.args="--runner=DirectRunner"`

or

`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.StarterPipeline -Dexec.args="--runner=FlinkRunner"`

in both cases i see the data written into destination kinesis stream.

However, if i run

`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.StarterPipeline -Dexec.args="--runner=SparkRunner"`

i get this stackoverflow error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:bs_test >-------------------------
[INFO] Building bs_test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- os:1.7.1:detect (set-property) @ bs_test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: osx
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.bitness: 64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 13.2
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 13
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 2
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: osx-x86_64
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protobuf:0.6.1:compile (default) @ bs_test ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 proto file(s) to /Users/viswajith/IdeaProjects/bs_test/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ bs_test ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/viswajith/IdeaProjects/bs_test/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ bs_test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/viswajith/IdeaProjects/bs_test/target/classes
[INFO] /Users/viswajith/IdeaProjects/bs_test/src/main/java/org/example/StarterPipeline.java: /Users/viswajith/IdeaProjects/bs_test/src/main/java/org/example/StarterPipeline.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /Users/viswajith/IdeaProjects/bs_test/src/main/java/org/example/StarterPipeline.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ bs_test ---
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:40 PM org.example.StarterPipeline createPipeline
INFO: Creating SparkRunner pipeline
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Read expand
WARNING: You are using a deprecated IO for Kinesis. Please migrate to module 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-amazon-web-services2'.
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder checkEqualsMethodDefined
WARNING: Can't verify serialized elements of type KinesisReaderCheckpoint have well defined equals method. This may produce incorrect results on some PipelineRunner implementations
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO$Write expand
WARNING: You are using a deprecated IO for Kinesis. Please migrate to module 'org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-amazon-web-services2'.
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner run
INFO: Executing pipeline using the SparkRunner.
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$TranslationModeDetector visitValue
INFO: Found unbounded PCollection KinesisIO.Read/Read(KinesisSource)/ParDo(UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapper)/ParMultiDo(UnboundedSourceAsSDFWrapper).output. Switching to streaming execution.
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.Checkpoint$CheckpointDir <init>
WARNING: The specified checkpoint dir /tmp/starterpipeline-viswajith-0308232441-cebb258c does not match a reliable filesystem so in case of failures this job may not recover properly or even at all.
Mar 08, 2023 3:24:41 PM org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.Checkpoint$CheckpointDir <init>
INFO: Checkpoint dir set to: /tmp/starterpipeline-viswajith-0308232441-cebb258c
[WARNING] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance (ReflectionUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init> (Groups.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init> (Groups.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService (Groups.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize (UserGroupInformation.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration (UserGroupInformation.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init> (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.instance$lzycompute (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.instance (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.get (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.getOrCreate$default$3 (StreamingContext.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext$.getOrCreate (JavaStreamingContext.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate (JavaStreamingContext.scala)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run (SparkRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run (SparkRunner.java:89)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:323)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:309)
    at org.example.StarterPipeline.main (StarterPipeline.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance (ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init> (Groups.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init> (Groups.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService (Groups.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize (UserGroupInformation.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration (UserGroupInformation.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.<init> (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.instance$lzycompute (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.instance (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.get (SparkHadoopUtil.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.getOrCreate$default$3 (StreamingContext.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext$.getOrCreate (JavaStreamingContext.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate (JavaStreamingContext.scala)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run (SparkRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run (SparkRunner.java:89)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:323)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:309)
    at org.example.StarterPipeline.main (StarterPipeline.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.time.Clock$SystemClock.instant (Clock.java:529)
    at java.time.Instant.now (Instant.java:273)
    at java.util.logging.LogRecord.<init> (LogRecord.java:229)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.innerNormalizedLoggingCallHandler (JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:147)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log (JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:172)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger (SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish (SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log (Logger.java:979)
.
.
.
.   <same error repeated until stack overflows >
.
.
.
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.innerNormalizedLoggingCallHandler (JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:156)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.361 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-08T15:24:43-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) on project bs_test: An exception occurred while executing the Java class. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: StackOverflowError -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[WARNING] 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ShutdownHookManager$2
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownHooksInOrder (ShutdownHookManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown (ShutdownHookManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run (ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$2
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.URLClassLoaderBuilder$ExecJavaClassLoader.loadClass (URLClassLoaderBuilder.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownHooksInOrder (ShutdownHookManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown (ShutdownHookManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run (ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
```

attaching beam pipeline code and pom file

```java
package org.example;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.InitialPositionInStream;
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisPartitioner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kinesis.KinesisRecord;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.checkerframework.checker.initialization.qual.Initialized;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.UnknownKeyFor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class StarterPipeline {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StarterPipeline.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();

        // Create pipeline
        Pipeline pipeline = createPipeline(options);

        // Read from Kinesis data stream
        PCollection<KinesisRecord> kinesisData = pipeline.apply(KinesisIO.read()
                .withStreamName("input-kinesis-stream")
                .withAWSClientsProvider(new DefaultCredentialsProviderClientsProvider(Regions.US_WEST_2))
                .withInitialPositionInStream(InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON)
                .withRequestRecordsLimit(5)
        );

        // Process elements using a custom DoFn
        PCollection<byte[]> processedData = kinesisData.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KinesisRecord, byte[]>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
                KinesisRecord record = c.element();
                byte[] data = record.getData().array();
                AllDataStreaming.StreamMessageWrapper message = AllDataStreaming.StreamMessageWrapper.parseFrom(data);
                c.output(message.toByteArray());
            }
        }));

        processedData.apply("Writing to Kinesis",
                KinesisIO
                        .write()
                        .withStreamName("output-kinesis-stream")
                        .withAWSClientsProvider(new DefaultCredentialsProviderClientsProvider(Regions.US_WEST_2))
                        .withPartitionKey(new SimpleHashPartitioner().toString())
        );

        // Run pipeline
        pipeline.run();
    }

    private static Pipeline createPipeline(PipelineOptions options) {
        if (options.as(FlinkPipelineOptions.class).getRunner().getSimpleName().equals("FlinkRunner")) {
            LOG.info("Creating FlinkRunner pipeline");
            return Pipeline.create(options.as(FlinkPipelineOptions.class));
        } else if (options.as(SparkPipelineOptions.class).getRunner().getSimpleName().equals("SparkRunner")) {
            LOG.info("Creating SparkRunner pipeline");

            // Set Spark configuration
            SparkPipelineOptions sparkPipelineOptions = options.as(SparkPipelineOptions.class);
            sparkPipelineOptions.setSparkMaster("local[2]");
            sparkPipelineOptions.setStreaming(true);
            return Pipeline.create(sparkPipelineOptions);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported runner specified: " + options.getRunner().getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    private static final class SimpleHashPartitioner implements KinesisPartitioner {
        @Override
        public @UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized String getPartitionKey(@UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized byte @UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized [] value) {
            return String.valueOf(Arrays.hashCode(value));
        }

        @Override
        public @UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized String getExplicitHashKey(@UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized byte @UnknownKeyFor @NonNull @Initialized [] value) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

pomfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>bs_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <beam.version>2.45.0</beam.version>
        <spark.version>3.1.3</spark.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-exec-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-exec-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j.version>2.0.5</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Direct Runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Flink Runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-flink-1.15</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spark Runner -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-spark-3</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-hadoop-file-system</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AWS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.kinesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Protobuf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- enforce jackson-databind version -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.5</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.22.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.53.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/protobuf/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDirectory>false</clearOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>set-property</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>detect</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>INFO</org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-exec-plugin.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                            <version>3.5.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

As you can see in the code, I tried adding sparkconfig to the code if sparkrunner is selected, added hadoop related dependencies, but the stackoverflow error wont go away. How can i resolve it?

beam version:2.45.0
java version: 11
spark version: 3.1.3

Comment: Unrelated to your question, I recommend you use Maven profiles to have a separate classpath per runner and then configure the runner using args, e.g. `--runner=SparkRunner`.

Comment: Also, you are attempting to use the deprecated `beam-sdks-java-io-kinesis` with AWS SDK v2, but it only supports SDK v1. Make sure to use `beam-sdks-java-io-amazon-web-services2` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Fix

To fix the issue remove `slf4j-jdk14` from your POM and if necessary, exclude it from other dependencies.

##### Why

There's an issue on your classpath. Spark forwards any logs to `JUL` to `SLF4J` (see `jul-to-slf4j`). If you attempt using JUL as logging backend for `SLF4J` logs are basically constantly send back and forth between the two. That's the Stackoverflow you're seeing.

Spark uses `log4j` for logging. On the classpath you will find `slf4j-log4j12` so that SLF4J emits log using Log4j. If using Spark I recommend using `Log4j` so that everything works seamlessly when running on a cluster as well.